# What's the word for an actor not getting a part in a movie?

Tags: casting, film-industry

What's the word for an actor not getting a part in a movie??

It's like some verb, it starts with an S. It's not scooped, but something like that.

There's an entire website about actors getting replaced by other actors, I think it has this word/concept as the name and it's driving me nuts that I can't remember it.

Comment: The noun for an actor/actress who did not get the job would be "server" :)

Comment: @Judy HAHAHA! That's brilliant!

Comment: @judy. I second what he said. Lil

Comment: Literally: unemployed

Comment: "Scabs" are non-union people brought in to replace union workers. It can happen in acting, but that's not used when you don't get the job.

Comment: [english.SE] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about englush language and as such it should have been asked on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Is the word you're looking for **shafted**?

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shaft):

> **shaft**
> *[shaft, shahft]*
> verb (used with object)
>
> 17. Informal. to treat in a harsh, unfair, or treacherous manner.

As the above dictionary entry implies, the term "shafted" usually means that the actor was unfairly treated. You wouldn't use this word if they just failed an audition and were legitimately rejected for a role.

[Here is an example](http://whatculture.com/film/10-actors-cruelly-shafted-franchise-reboots.php) of such usage.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's *snubbed*, as in this example:

> But when it came to making the now iconic movie version, [Julie Andrews] was passed over in favour of Audrey Hepburn because Julie "wasn't known at that time."
>
> Later commenting on the **snub**, she said: "Audrey and I became good friends and one day she said to me, 'Julie, you should have done the role … but I didn't have the guts to turn it down'."

<sup>Source: [The Gladstone Observer](https://www.gladstoneobserver.com.au/news/role-julie-andrews-was-snubbed/3222566/)</sup>

Also:

> Was Edward Norton **snubbed** for the role of Hulk in Joss Whedon's Avengers?

<sup>Source: [Gizmodo](https://io9.gizmodo.com/5583978/was-edward-norton-snubbed-for-the-role-of-hulk-in-joss-whedons-avengers)</sup>

It's also widely used in the entertainment industry when a creative professional is not given an award that many believe they deserve. So often you will hear of actors being "**snubbed** for an Oscar".

Answer (score 0):

How about "Swapped"

as in

https://www.theloop.ca/12-tv-characters-who-got-replaced-with-different-actors/

I thought about this before and that is the best term I could come up with